# reference for strongly continuous semi-groups

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, symplectic-geometry

At the moment I am trying to understand the proof of the Fredholm property in Salamon's notes on Floer homology. There I came across the notion of an unbounded operator on a (real) Hilbert space which is symmetric and does not have $0$ as an eigenvalue. It is then claimed that the operator generates strongly continuous semigroups on the respective eigenspaces.

In fact I would like to understand these notions, but I don't seem to  find good introductory texts. Since the topic seems rather old googling mostly gives me very recent result which are in particular much too specific.

Can anyone give me a reference on symmetric unbounded operators on real Hilbert spaces and their corresponding semigroups?

Comment: Did you try Yosida's book on functional analysis?

Comment: It would help if you gave a precise reference to Salamon's notes (link + page number) then one could check more easily if a certain result fits.

Comment: The reference is http://www.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/floer.pdf, page 17, step 1.

Comment: Engel and Nagel!

Comment: @ Jonas: Thank you, a very appealing reference. @t.b. I find the book to be somewhat difficult to read because of its age... Sorry!

Comment: No problem it is not *my* book, but I'd say it is definitely worth the effort... @Jonas: Ping!

Comment: Pazy is also nice, but is more focused on analytic semigroups. By the way, the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck semigroup is very nice and has cute properties. @t.b.: Ping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Engel and Nagel was mentioned in the comments, the short version

http://www.fa.uni-tuebingen.de/research/publications/2006/a-short-course-on-operator-semigroups/A_Short_Course_on_Operator_Semigroups.pdf

Is a great introduction.

Comment: I actually found Engel and Nagel quite enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it useful to look at Chapter 6 of 
"Linear Operators and Their Spectra" by E. Brian Davies,
though he works on Banach spaces.

His book is available [online](http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/staff/eb_davies/printmaster.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You can try "Semigroups of Linear Operators and Applications to Partial Differential Equations" by Pazy.

Answer (score 1):

For a first introduction I liked the chapters on Operator Theory and Semigroups in *An Introduction to Partial Differential Equations* by Rogers and Renardy. It keeps things simple, explicit and gets the main ideas across. After reading these introductory chapters other functional analysis texts will be much easier to read.